# Pointer triangle in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, geometry

I have a simple quastion.
I have this C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num1, i, j, x, y;
    Console.WriteLine("enter number");
    num1=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (i=1; i<=num1; i++){
        for (j=1; j<i+1; j++) {
        Console.Write(i);

        }Console.Write("\n"); 
    }
     for (x=num1; x>=0; x--){
        for (y=0; y<x; y++) {
        Console.Write(x);

        }Console.Write("\n"); 
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]
The middle line is repeat twice

Which print triangle from numbers.
The problem is that the middle line is repeated twice.
My question is how can I change the loop, so the middle line numbers will repeat twice?
Wish for help, thanks!

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what your code actually does, and what is the middle line, where do you have code for the middle line?

Comment: You forced me copy-paste this code to see that incredible triangle!

Comment: No! I ulploaded an Image, is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because both for loops include `num1` as an inclusive condition:

```
for (i=1; i<=num1; i++){
    // num1 is the last number in this loop
}
for (x=num1; x>=0; x--){
    // num1 is the first number in this loop
}
```

Change the first loop to stop BEFORE `num1`:

```
for (i=1; i<num1; i++){
```

Answer (score 3):

Uhh change

```
for (x=num1; x>=0; x--){
```

to

```
for (x=num1-1; x>=0; x--){
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.Write("enter number: ");
int num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Enumerable.Range(1, num)
          .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, num - 1).Reverse())
          .Select(x => String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(x.ToString(),x)))
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(line => Console.WriteLine(line));
```

Comment: I was impressed by triangle :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num1, i, j, x, y;
    Console.WriteLine("enter number");
    num1=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (i=1; i<num1; i++){
        for (j=1; j<i+1; j++) {
        Console.Write(i);

        }Console.Write("\n"); 
    }
     for (x=num1; x>=0; x--){
        for (y=0; y<x; y++) {
        Console.Write(x);

        }Console.Write("\n"); 
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```